# Facebook Bot Attachment Unavailable issue

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, api-ai

I am building a bot for facebook messenger. It was all working fine and suddenly facing "Attachment Unavailable" issue. Funny thing is, bot is working all fine on messenger app on phone devices. But facing this in desktop messenger version.[image] Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Yes. I have also same problem.

Comment: I seems like the issue has been already reported 
 https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/643964919115135/?hc_location=ufi